# Adding selector to listview item

Tags: android

I am using the following xml code to show smooth top white strip and bottom white strip on list item selection. The problem is that it shows gradient on list item selection.I think, I am missing something in xml,Please help me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>

            <gradient
                android:startColor="@android:color/white"
                android:centerColor="@android:color/transparent"
                android:endColor="@android:color/white"
                android:angle="90" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: well your center color is transparent, shouldnt it also be white?

Comment: Is the issue that you have a gradient or that the gradient you do have is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- If you simply want a background for your list item, use the following -->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"><stroke android:color="@color/popup_border" android:width="1dp"/>  <!-- For border/outline(Remove this line if you don't want border/outline)-->
            <gradient android:startColor="@android:color/white" android:centerColor="@android:color/transparent" android:endColor="@android:color/white" android:angle="270" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```